Efficient way to calculate this sequence of probabilities based on subsets of [0,1] and ultimately find an expectation
(I've framed this as a probability question, but it's fundamentally a question about the total length of intervals making up a set.)
For each $m \in \mathbb{N}$, define a subset of $[0,1]$
$A_m = \{x \in [0,1]: \frac{n}{2^m-1} < x < \frac{n+1}{2^m},$ for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$
Let random variable $X$ be uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$.
What is $p(m) = \text{Pr}[X \in A_m$, $X \notin A_1 \cup A_2 \cup ... \cup A_{m-1}]$?
I've worked through cases to find specific values of $p(m)$.
$A_1 = (0, \frac12)$, so
$$p(1) = \text{Pr}[X \in A_1] = \frac12$$
$A_2 = (0, \frac14) \cup (\frac13, \frac24) \cup (\frac23, \frac34)$ so
$A_2 \backslash A_1 = (\frac23, \frac34)$ giving
$$p(2) = \frac{1}{(2^2-1) \cdot 2^2} = \frac{1}{12}$$
Similar work by laboriously considering which intervals in $A_m$ are not in $A_i$ for $i < m$ gets me
$$p(3) = \frac{4}{(2^3-1) \cdot 2^3} = \frac{1}{14}$$
$$p(4) = \frac{11}{(2^4-1) \cdot 2^4} = \frac{11}{240}$$
$$p(5) = \frac{42}{(2^5-1) \cdot 2^5}$$
$$p(6) = \frac{109}{(2^6-1) \cdot 2^6}$$
etc
I've got as far as
$$p(12) = \frac{166393}{(2^{12}-1) \cdot 2^{12}}$$
But I can't put my finger on an efficient way (eg some recurrence relation) to churn these out.  Is there one?  (In case you are wondering $4, 11, 42, 109$ does not match anything in OEIS).
One goal is to find the following expectations:
Define random variable $N$ to be the smallest $m$ such that $X \in A_m$.  Then $E[N] = \displaystyle \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} m \cdot p(m)$ hence it would be helpful to develop expressions for $p(m)$.  What is $E[N]$?
Even more challenging, what is $E[X | N = m] = \displaystyle \frac{\int_{A_m \backslash A_1 \cup ... A_{m-1}} x \space dx}{p(m)}$?
